# Mapping large quantity of domains to a Google App Engine application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

Does anyone know if there is a way to map more than 20 domains to a Google App Engine application?

Currently, I'm hitting a limit of 20 domain aliases in my Google Apps account and thus am unable to map more domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed with Google customer service that this is simply not possible. I had to move to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) because of this limitation, which is underwhelming.